# Highlight GridView Rows only when Delete button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

what i want do is to when the user click on Delete button i want to highlight the entire row and ask for confirmation before it deletes, and the below is my code and iw ant to execute two steps:
1) hightlight the entire row
2) ask the for confirmation.

```
protected void gvOrg_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Button btnDelete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
    if (btnDelete != null)
     { 
          //btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red);
          btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format(textForMessage, "Id:  " + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Id"), "Name:  " + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void gvOrg_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  Button btnDelete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
  if (btnDelete != null)
  { 
    btnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
      String.Format(@"return DeleteRow('{0}',{1});", 
        e.Row.ClientID,e.Row.RowIndex));
  }
}

//javascript
function DeleteRow(rowId, rowIdx)
{
  HighlightRow(rowId, "#FF0000");
  var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');
  if(!result)
    HighlightRow(rowId, rowIdx % 2 ? "#DEEEE9" : "#FFFFFF");
  return result;
}

function HighlightRow(rowId, color)
{
  var row = document.getElementById(rowId);    
  row.style.background = color;
}
```

Comment: one small thing i foud that i have alternating row ` <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DEEEE9" Font-Size="8pt" />` so how can i restore the same alternating row?